# Breakdown this memory leak caused by a closure (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures, lexical-scope

I'm trying to advance my understanding of closures in JavaScript.

I came across [this](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-memory-management-how-to-handle-4-common-memory-leaks-3f28b94cfbec) article...and in section 3 they explained how certain closures cause memory leaks in the browser. The example originated from [this](https://blog.meteor.com/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak-8b47d2e7f156) article.

However I'm having a difficult time understanding how the closure is causing the leakage. I understand that **someMethod** and **unUsed** are saving a reference to its shared lexical environment.

But what is meant when the article states that the reference to **originalThing** from inside **unUsed** is maintaining this shared environment open? Arn't both **unUsed** and **someMethod** doing this? 
Also, how is **longStr** compounding on it self on each call to **replaceThing**?

Can you please break this down line by line, one execution at a time?

Thanks!

```
var theThing = null;

var replaceThing = function () {
    var originalThing = theThing;

    var unused = function () {
        if (originalThing) // a reference to 'originalThing'
            console.log("hi");
    };

    theThing = {
         longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
         someMethod: function () {
             console.log("message");
         }
    };
};

setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

Comment: `unused` is never called, and no reference to it is stored outside of the method.  So that variable will be available to be garbage collected after the `replaceThing` method ends.

Comment: OP's referenced article from 2013 is referring to it leaking because of the way closure scope variables were kept.  What Taplar says was explained as holding true, only if no closures hold references to the variables in their scopes, because the variables get propagated to the environment of all closures in the scope.  No longer reproducible in latest Chrome, so most likely fixed relatively recently with smarter heuristics.